# Change page layout on windows resize

Tags: css

I have a page with a sidebar on the left and content on the right.

```
___________ _____________________
|         | |                   |
|         | |                   |
|         | |                   |
| sidebar | |      content      |
|         | |                   |
|         | |                   |
|         | |                   |
|_________| |___________________|
```

When window gets small enough, I would like to have my sidebar move below.

```
 _____________________
 |                   |
 |                   |
 |                   |
 |      content      |
 |                   |
 |                   |
 |                   |
 |___________________|
 _____________________
 |                   |
 |      sidebar      |
 |___________________|
```

I tried to do it with CSS but I only know how to do it when sidebar is originally on the right.
Then I thought I could use jQuery on Window.resize and Window.load, but that was wrong on so many levels :(

Is it doable?

Comment: Have you looked into the flexbox model?

Comment: have you tried the media query.

Comment: @j08691 No, not really. I read that the support for flexbox is not that great yet.

Comment: @Aravind Sivam I do have quite a few of them. The probem is that I have get_sidebar() before the main content and I cannot get them in the reversed order. I was thinking about calling get_sidebar() twice, before and after the main content, and then use the query to make one of them content="". Again, it was a bad idea :(

Comment: On the media query you need to  change the css float left and right I think this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it. After all, seems that jQuery was not a bad idea :)

I used 2 sidebars. The first (regular) one is displayed by WordPress.

`<div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">`

After the content, I added another sidebar. Just an empty div.

```
<div id="secondary2" class="widget-area" role="complementary"></div>
```

Then I used jQuery to move content from one to another, leaving the other one empty. I think it works. If anyone sees any downsides, please do let me know ;)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var sidebar_original = $('#secondary').html();

$(window).resize(function() {

    var sidebar_content = $('#secondary').html();
    var windowsize = $('.wrapper').width();

    if ((windowsize) >= 770 && sidebar_content !== sidebar_original ){

        $('#secondary').html(sidebar_original);
        $('#secondary2').html("");

    }else if((windowsize) < 770 && sidebar_content === sidebar_original){

        $('#secondary').html("");
        $('#secondary2').html(sidebar_original);
    }
});

$(window).trigger('resize');
```

});

Answer (score 3):

Another option with media queries.  This time placing the sidebar after the content in the markup.

```css
.content {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: inline-block; /* inline block so the sidebar can be after the content in the markup */
  width: calc(100% - 10em); /* 100% minus the width of the sidebar */
}
.sidebar {
  background-color: lightpink;
  float: left; /* floated left so it appears to the left of the content */
  width: 10em;
}
@media (max-width: 30em) { /* when the width is less than 30em, make both of the widths 100% */
  .content,
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>This is the main content div</p>
  <p>Isn't it beautiful?</p>
  <p>I have so much awesome content!</p>
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
  <p>I am your sidebar</p>
  <p>I'm sad I'm not more important...</p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cxx04wcc/3/

Comment: Yeah, this is what I had before. The problem I found with this is selecting content on page. Even though divs are positioned visually as intended, when you try to select content with the mouse, it is in the wrong order. Still, looks like the best idea so far.

Answer (score 0):

Set your items  to `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`, then define an explicit width / height (px) for them. This will cause the elements to change lines. If you wish to use percents, define a `min-width`.

```css
.flow {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block; /*or table */
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 375px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="flow">
    Block 1
  </div>

  <div class="flow">
    Block 2
  </div>
```

`min-width` designates the width it must be until it wraps.

Comment: I just noticed you can't resize it. Open it in "Full page" and shrink your browser size I guess.

Comment: Hmmm... I need the order reversed... I need block 2 on top, once they can no longer fit side by side...

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple. We can make a common structure:

```css
#wrapper {
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
}

#wrapper div {
    float:left;
}

#content {
    height:100%;
    width:70%;
    background-color:blue;
}

#sidebar {
    width:29%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:red;
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

And to change when the window size changes, you can use the *media queries*. I've created this rule: `@media screen and (max-width: 500px)`. It is interpreted: "when the screen width size is 500px or less...". So, we can do a new rule to change the elements:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    /* New rules here */
}
```

You said that need the sidebar stay on the right, then when the screen changes it go to bottom. I did the sidebar go to the bottom of the content giving the content height. See:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #wrapper div {
        float:none;
        width:100%;
        position:absolute;
    }
    #sidebar {
        height:200px;
        top:100%;
    }
}
```

---

You will need adapt it to your needs, but it is a base.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2sqL7eaq/

Comment: What? top:100%
I have never seen that before. It just might do the trick. I have to try it,

Comment: It's the height of `content`. For sidebar go to bottom of it, you need specific to it go `x` pixels bottom, so `content` height's.

Comment: I think it is parent's height. My sidebar went bellow my footer :(